# Why does fetching a .php file using post return a blank result

Tags: javascript, php, html

Okay, running this in a Node.JS enviornment (using node-fetch) works just fine, it returns the expected result.

```
fetch(`<URL>/api.php?f=developmentIsAnnoying2`,{method:"post",body:JSON.stringify({time:0,queue:["a song"],
repeat:false,loop:false})}).then(d=>d.text()).then(console.log);
```

But running the same code in Google Chrome, using the same domain, returns an absolutely blank result. There are no errors, on any side (client, php, nor API).

**PHP:**

```
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        case "POST":
            echo file_get_contents('php://input');
        break;
        default:
            echo '{"message":"This is a place holder."}';
        break;
    }
```

What's the deal!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it gets mad about the JSON header, despite the fact all data is ALWAYS supposed to be JSON, and was used that way in testing.

So, I had to remove this part:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: I'd still like it if someone could elaborate why this weird behavior happens, it doesn't seem like it should.